# How to access internet from VM instance in Openstack?

Tags: networking, ping, connection, openstack-neutron

I've been scratching my head for last 5 days, almost went to the end of Internet, read a lot of tutorials, made a lot of re installations an re configurations of openstack but at the and of the day could not resolve this problem... So i think you guys ( and girls ) are my last hope.

Okay to the point.

- LAN - 192.168.0.0/24
- Router IP (Gateway) - 192.168.0.1
- MacOS Laptop - 192.168.0.192 / Has internet access
- CentOS 7 running on VirtualBox with promiscuous mode set for all and with ip 192.168.0.22 / Has internet access

The problem is I cannot ping my physical router ( 192.168.0.1 ) nor access Internet from any of my VM instance and not even from external router ( linux namespace ). What is weird, I can ping VM instances (which have floating IP's) from my MacOS Laptop and CentOS7 VM. Also there is no problem to ssh them in both cases. In addition, firewalld is disabled on my host machine and ipv4 port forwarding is set to 1, port security setting are configured to allow traffic flow on port 80,20 and ICMP both Ingress and Egress.

Hope this set of configurations will help you find the bug.
Thanks in advance !

My ip a command on CentOS 7: https://textuploader.com/16d1u

My packstack answer file: https://textuploader.com/16d1g

My /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br-ex configuration: https://textuploader.com/16d1p

My /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 configuration: https://textuploader.com/16d1z

brctl show and ovs-vsctl show: https://textuploader.com/16d1i

neutron net-list: https://textuploader.com/16dta

Network topology: #https://ibb.co/drJS3Bf#

**UPDATE 19.01.20**

I've created a new external network in Openstack environment but this time as a gateway I used 192.168.0.22 which is my CentOS host ip (before I used 192.168.0.1) . After this, I can ping my physical router (192.168.0.1) from any place (VM instances, router namespace) but still cannot ping 8.8.8.8... When trying to, I get a "Redirect Host" message. -> https://pastebin.com/bSQhbkBc

Comment: Can you share your iptables and nat in you VM instance.

Comment: Thank's for replaying to this post @Nazia Jahan Trisha. I'm using a small cirros image so i don't have iptables installed but here you can check ip r command: https://pastebin.com/Z18FLd5W   ,here you got iptables for CentOS - https://textuploader.com/16dxk , here for qrouter (router namespace) https://textuploader.com/16dxl

Comment: Here is also a  tcpdump output from qrouter's namespace https://textuploader.com/16dxg (link text). I pinged it both from virtual network as well as from physical one, also: Mac < - >VM Instance, VM Instance -> Router's physical gateway, but I think it didn't capture it... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From the topology, one possibility could be that, the bridge device you have for the VM's, you may need to enable routing there.

Comment: Could you tell me something more how to do it? Is there any config file for this?